# Display amount of comments from different database table

Tags: angularjs

Before I start coding I'm trying to figure out how I'd do it first. So what I want to do is to display a list of articles, by simply loading it from a database for example: `getAllArticles()`.

The list will display all the titles from the articles. Nothing difficult about that.

However, there's a chance to comment on that article so all the comments will be stored in a new database tabel with the `ID` of the article.

I'll probably have to load them with `getAllCommentsById()` but how do I display the amount of comments next to each article in an `ng-repeat`?

I don't have any code yet, but let's say it will look like this:

### Angular

```
<div ng-repeat='article in articles'>
    <p>{{amount}}</p>
    <p>{{article.title}}</p>
</div>

$scope.articles = getAllQuestions();
```

### Article database

```
{
  "id":1,
  "title": "Article 1"
}
{
  "id":2,
  "title": "Article 2"
}
```

### Comments database

```
{
  "id":1,
  "comment": "Lorem ipsum",
  "article_id": 1
},
{
  "id":2,
  "comment": "Lorem ipsum",
  "article_id": 1
},
{
  "id":3,
  "comment": "Lorem ipsum",
  "article_id": 2
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can do it in two several ways.

1. You can add a counter of the comment relatives to an article in the articles object
2. Create a function in angular's controller that give the number of comments of an article

   $scope.countComments = function(articleId) {
       ...
   }
3. Create an angular service that count the comments of each article

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would you do 2 and 3 then? If I have a function that counts the comments, how do I get them in that list next to the right article title?

Comment: Hi that's the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ASpBBQlo1WFQuxkwN9cB?p=preview) with the example

Comment: In this example there are the two versions. With scope function and with filter

Comment: Oh thank you so much. That's very helpful, really appreciated